# when shooting constantly repeats and goes faster every key stroke

Tags: java, timer, keyboard, key, imageicon

Ok so i'm going to try to explain this, well I created a shoot method in a class that contains my bluespell, and all of it's constructors, well the problem is when I press space once it constantly shoots without me pressing it again, and if I press it twice the speed at which it fires doubles and it starts to contain more than one x and y position on my grid I just want the spell to fire when fired and I only need one item because I don't want there to be more than one instance of it on the grid I want it to be that the player cannot fire until the spell has left the grid, here's my code thanks oh and I only have it called in my key released seeing as it should only do it once the key has been released, but if that should change please let me know thanks :)

```
   public void shootSpell(){
    final BlueSpell b = new BlueSpell(GoodGuy.getx(), GoodGuy.gety() +1, BlueSpellWizard());
    int delay = 100;

    ActionListener taskPerformed = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


            if(b.gety() != 19){

                WizardCells[b.getx()][b.gety()].setIcon(null);
                WizardCells[b.getx()][b.changey(b.gety()+1)].setIcon(b.getIcon());

            }

            else{
                WizardCells[b.getx()][b.gety()].setIcon(null);
                b.changex(GoodGuy.getx());
                b.changey(GoodGuy.gety() +1);


            }

        }
    };

    new Timer(delay, taskPerformed).start();



    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){


            GoodSpell.shootSpell();


            }
```

Comment: Is this all in one Class?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)! Your task should not repeat every 100 milliseconds. If I understand your code, you should run the code from your `ActionListener` in a new thread.

```
// Something like this,
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (b.gety() != 19) {
            WizardCells[b.getx()][b.gety()].setIcon(null);
            WizardCells[b.getx()][b.changey(b.gety() + 1)].setIcon(b
                    .getIcon());
        } else {
            WizardCells[b.getx()][b.gety()].setIcon(null);
            b.changex(GoodGuy.getx());
            b.changey(GoodGuy.gety() + 1);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to do a check if the spell is currently in view/activate prior to initiating a new spell in the shoot() method...

```
public void shootSpell(){
     //do a check here if a spell is already running!
    final BlueSpell b = new BlueSpell(GoodGuy.getx(), GoodGuy.gety() +1, BlueSpellWizard());
    int delay = 100;
 //......
```

So in your method that is updating the spell going accross the screen you either need to have a flag in there if its still active, or if you are running it in a new thread, save that thread to a global var and check to see if the thread is running prior instantiating a new `BlueSpell()`